# Face recognition software (and SDK)

Tags: windows, face-recognition

I've been looking for a software (that has a SDK avaliable) to recognize faces from a camera and from a image. It doesn't matter if it is paid or not.

So far, I came up with these:

- [Luxand FaceSDK](https://www.luxand.com/facesdk/)
- [OpenCV](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23191/Face-and-Eyes-Detection-Using-OpenCV)

FaceSDK is perfect, but the licence is way out of what I can pay (U$10k) and I haven't had any time to play with OpenCV, but I'd like to have a bit more suggestions on what I can use.

It is going to be used into a comercial environment, so if it needs a special licence for it, a note on that would be appreciated.

Comment: Recognise faces in general (i.e. "that is a face at [x1,y1] to [x2,y2]") or specific (i.e. "that is Bob")? Any data beyond presence and location of the face?

Comment: Both. I'll need to see a face first (like that 'that is a face from x to y"), store the image of its face and later, using the saved image, compare to another live-captured image.

Comment: I don't recall if there is any API available but Google's Picassa has pretty good face recognition.

Comment: Picasa had APIs but looks like none of them involved allowing 3rd party apps to acess its features. Also, they're deprecated. Seems that Google doesn't want to share this with us!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [pyFaces](https://code.google.com/p/pyfaces/) which has a number of features for face detection using EigenFaces but there doesn't seem to be a lot of activity on it lately.  It is however open source so may be a good starting point for you.

For face detection you can use python with OpenCV bindings as detailed [here](http://www.realpython.com/blog/python/face-recognition-with-python/).

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you the [Ozeki Camera SDK](http://www.camera-sdk.com/). This is a camera software toolkit that can be used to implement e.g. [object detection](http://www.camera-sdk.com/p_244-how-to-implement-object-detection-in-c-onvif.html) in C#, specifically [face detection](http://www.camera-sdk.com/p_267-how-to-implement-face-detection-in-c-onvif.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, leonidas – but how does it meet the requirements? Does it (explicitely!) support *face detection*? What about the license part? Why are you recommending it (e.g. what are your personal experiences, or other background that makes this solution appear to be great)? Please read our [answering guideline](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) – we aim for the highest possible quality here; just a name and a link we don't feel sufficient :)